# Unable to get a window, abort

Tags: python, kivy

I'm getting what seems to be a common error running the Kivy hello world program. I've tried the solutions I've seen here: manually install `gstreamer`, adding it to `PATH` and installing `PySDL2`. My OS is Windows 7, all other version info is in the error log.

```
# you need this two lines:
import os
os.environ['KIVY_IMAGE'] = 'pil,sdl2'

#kivy program
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()
```

The error log:

```
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\xyz\.kivy\logs\kivy_16-11-19_11.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:24:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_pil, img_sdl2 (img_tex, img_dds, img_ffpyplayer, img_gif ignored)
[INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO              ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
[INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO              ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <3.1.0 - Build 8.15.10.2538>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Intel>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Intel(R) HD Graphics Family>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 1
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Shading version <1.40  - Intel Build 8.15.10.2538>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO              ] [Shader      ] fragment shader: <No errors.>
[INFO              ] [Shader      ] vertex shader: <No errors.>
[INFO              ] [Shader      ] program: <No errors.>
[CRITICAL          ] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!
sdl2 - AttributeError: tobytes
  File "C:\Program Files\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 67, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "C:\Program Files\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 138, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "C:\Program Files\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 722, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "C:\Program Files\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 255, in create_window
    super(WindowSDL, self).create_window()
  File "C:\Program Files\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 897, in create_window
    self.render_context = RenderContext()
  File "kivy\graphics\instructions.pyx", line 756, in kivy.graphics.instructions.RenderContext.__init__ (kivy\graphics\instructions.c:10729)
  File "C:\Program Files\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 512, in __init__
    self.filename = arg
  File "C:\Program Files\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 700, in _set_filename
    mipmap=self._mipmap, nocache=self._nocache)
  File "C:\Program Files\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 430, in load
    im = loader(filename, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 198, in __init__
    self._data = self.load(filename)
  File "C:\Program Files\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\img_pil.py", line 101, in load
    return list(self._img_read(im))
  File "C:\Program Files\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\img_pil.py", line 86, in _img_read
    img_tmp.mode.lower(), img_tmp.tobytes())
  File "C:\Program Files\python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 514, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)

[CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
 Exception SystemExit: 1 in 'kivy.properties.dpi2px' ignored
[CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Comment: How did you install kivy?

Comment: @inclement As listed in https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#installation, except I downloaded gstreamer and installed from the local copy

Answer (score 55):

In cmd go to python34 and then to Scripts and install the following:

```
pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
pip install kivy.deps.angle
pip install kivy
```

Comment: For the people that run into this like me: the pip install pypiwin32 can give an error because pywin32 is possibly already installed and cannot be uninstalled. For me it workend when i ran the items in the second line via a seperate pip install and ignore the pypiwin32 install error.

Comment: FYI For people out there, this great answer seems also applied for other versions of python. Working well in python 3.7.3

Comment: Did not worked for me, Windows 10 and Python 3.8.6 installing Kivy as is said in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59346655/8849755).

Comment: @user171780 You should downgrade your python to 3.7. PyInstaller does not work properly with 3.8

Answer (score 10):

Try putting `<python dir>\share\sdl2\bin` to your path, it should do the trick. The thing is that it can't find the sdl2 binary it works with. There probably even isn't any PIL ***window*** [provider](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master/kivy/core/window), so using environment variable won't do a thing for creating a window (it'll be used as an image provider though).

I'm not really familiar with PySDL2, so I can't help you with that, however I made an [installer](https://github.com/KeyWeeUsr/KivyInstaller) for Kivy on Windows to make things easier for beginners.

There are basically two ways you'll end up with anyway:

1. You'll put the `bin` folders to a `PATH` variable permanently

   I consider it really stupid unless you're sure you won't delete Python or the folder, otherwise you'll have a ghost folder in `PATH` + all other programs will have an access to files in `bin` folders via `PATH`
2. You'll have a batch file that does that temporarily

   Only programs ran from the console/batch will have an access to the `bin` folder.

The installer does that for you and in fact does even installing from scratch (no Python) or many other things.

In case you haven't installed the Kivy [dependencies](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#installation), please do it first.

Comment: I'll try and report back. I no longer think I need PySDL2, as kivy.deps.sdl2 is a dependency.

Comment: If your using Anaconda C:\Users\[USER NAME]\Anaconda2\share\gstreamer\bin

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about Windows or Linux, but on python-for-android at the very top you need to put:

```
#qpy:kivy
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.1') # replace with your current kivy version !
```

Comment: Line 1. #qpy:kivy line 2. import kivy line 3. kivy.require('1.10.0'), for me just pip install kivy did all the needed upgrades automatically. the glory of qpython

Answer (score 3):

Disable the 3D acceleration and the 2D video acceleration in the display settings of the virtual software (aka vmbox, vmware).
I think this will work for you , it works for me after lots of tries.

Comment: I also got it to work by installing `pygame` from pip. `pip3 install pygame` and then it worked, I didn't have to disable 3D acceleration in my VM.

Comment: @jamescampbell installing pygame solved my problem you could create an answer (instead of just a comment since it is one of viable solutions)

Comment: @Tim good point. Doing that now.

Answer (score 3):

I just found a quick fix

1. Once you have installed Kivy using `pip`
2. navigate to *C:\Users\(accountname)\.kivy\* and open the *config.ini* file
3. change the *`multisamples = 0`* from `= 2`  then restart your
   computer. This will save other issues too like

> [CRITICAL] [GL          ] Minimum required OpenGL version (2.0) NOT
>   found!

This worked for me on windows 7 64 bit, python3.5(32 bit) with Kivy *version 1.10.0*

Answer (score 3):

I'm using windows 10 and python 3.6, and I installed kivy using pip.
None of above solution helped, but then I uninstall the kivy with pip, and install kivy again with conda according to https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html#installation and it worked.

The packages conda installed for me are:
The following packages will be downloaded:

```
package                    |            build
---------------------------|-----------------
freetype-2.8.1             |           vc14_0         469 KB  conda-forge
sdl2_mixer-2.0.4           |       h6538335_0          83 KB  conda-forge
sdl2-2.0.10                |       h6538335_0         4.3 MB  conda-forge
kivy-1.11.1                |   py36hbc14df2_0        20.2 MB  conda-forge
sdl2_image-2.0.2           |                0         293 KB  conda-forge
glew-2.0.0                 |    he025d50_1002         722 KB  conda-forge
sdl2_ttf-2.0.14            |       h8909db8_1          25 KB  conda-forge
smpeg2-2.0.0               |       h6538335_1         131 KB  conda-forge
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Yeah man, thanks a lot! This was the problem for me! :)

Answer (score 3):

I got this to work by installing pygame from pip.

`pip3 install pygame` and then it worked.

That way, I didn't have to disable 3D acceleration in my VM.