# Kivy - windows - Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all

Tags: python, windows, graphics, kivy

I am starting with kivy. here is the sample code I am running.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label
kivy.require('1.9.0')


class HelloApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello World!')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HelloApp().run()
```

and here is the traceback I am getting:

```
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\monac\.kivy\logs\kivy_16-11-23_9.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 20:20:57) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO              ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
[INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO              ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.5.0 NVIDIA 373.06'>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'NVIDIA Corporation'>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'GeForce GTX 960M/PCIe/SSE2'>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 5
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.50 NVIDIA'>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[WARNING           ] [Image       ] Unable to load image <C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\data\glsl\default.png>
[CRITICAL          ] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!
sdl2 - Exception: SDL2: Unable to load image
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 67, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 138, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 722, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 255, in create_window
    super(WindowSDL, self).create_window()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 897, in create_window
    self.render_context = RenderContext()
  File "kivy\graphics\instructions.pyx", line 756, in kivy.graphics.instructions.RenderContext.__init__ (kivy\graphics\instructions.c:10729)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 512, in __init__
    self.filename = arg
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 700, in _set_filename
    mipmap=self._mipmap, nocache=self._nocache)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 430, in load
    im = loader(filename, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 198, in __init__
    self._data = self.load(filename)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\img_sdl2.py", line 42, in load
    raise Exception('SDL2: Unable to load image')

[CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
 Exception ignored in: 'kivy.properties.dpi2px'
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\utils.py", line 513, in __get__
     retval = self.func(inst)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\metrics.py", line 175, in dpi
     EventLoop.ensure_window()
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 126, in ensure_window
     sys.exit(1)
 SystemExit: 1
[CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

I am running on windows 10 64bits. I have installed all the dependencies except `gstreamer` which I won't need at the moment.

I am also not sure why I am getting this error:

```
[WARNING           ] [Image       ] Unable to load image <C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\data\glsl\default.png>
```

The file exists and I am running my code as admin to avoid access rights problems.

Thank you.

Comment: do you have `pygame` installed?

Comment: @AminEtesamian, No. But for this version of kivy it is not required.

Comment: I have encountered this error before and the solution was to install pygame. I know the screen provider is sdl2 but that worked for me

Comment: @AminEtesamian, I tried installing `pygame`. I still have the same error. Thanks for trying to help. any other ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [kivy - unable to get a window, abort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697876/kivy-unable-to-get-a-window-abort)

Comment: @AminEtesamian No pygame. Pygame has been deprecated a long ago, use `sdl2`. And wheels, it's much simpler if you don't work with cython code.

Answer (score 4):

You have to install the dependencies for Kivy.

Follow the instructions [here](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html)

```
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
```

will do what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this same error after installing kivy and its dependencies prior to creating my virtualenv with `--system-site-packages`. To resolve it, I had to leave my virtualenv, uninstall all packages kivy, enter my virtualenv, and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

you have to install all dependency 
check this url in detail
https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#kivy-dependencies
i followed all step by step 
don't forget install
kivy.deps.angle, kivy.deps.glew, kivy.deps.gstreamer, kivy.deps.sdl2

Answer (score 0):

In the display settings of the virtual software (aka vmbox, vmware) disable the 3D acceleration and the 2D video acceleration . I think this will work for you , it works for me after lots of tries.

Answer (score 0):

Some might have had the same issue when using a dist generated by pyinstaller.

Kivy doc reminds the developer to add those dependencies. https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html#pyinstaller-default-hook

but i had to add **angle** to make it work in my context.

```
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew, angle

coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('examples-path\\demo\\touchtracer\\'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins+ angle.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='touchtracer')
```