# Python Kivy Unable to get a Window, abort

Tags: python

This is my first post here. I am a beginner at programming with Python so please be specefic with your awnsers :)

So when I try to run a simple script to create a window it gives the error 'Unable to get a Window, abort' I looked at other posts and tried to apply the sulutions given there but nothing seems to work. I am running it on windows 10 through Pycharm.

this is the code im trying to run:

```
from kivy.app import App

class app(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().run()
```

Comment: @aaron this one for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697876/kivy-unable-to-get-a-window-abort

Comment: @aaron it first wanted me to install 'Cython' so I did. Then it gave this error in cmd: 'failed with error code 1' with a lot of other stuff.

Comment: @aaron added it in awnser

Answer (score 0):

I FIXED IT! After reinstalling python and kivy and then changing my path to just 'C:\Program Files\Python36' and nothing else it finally worked.