# How to deal with Kivy installing error in Python 3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, kivy, python-3.8

I have installed every necessary code in Python from Kivy, but the last one I need which one is **python -m pip install kivy** gets me an error like this:

```
ERROR: Dependency for context.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for compiler.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for context_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for fbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for gl_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for opengl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for opengl_utils.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for shader.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for stencil_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for scissor_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for texture.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for vbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for vertex.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for vertex_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for cgl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for cgl_mock.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for cgl_gl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for cgl_glew.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for cgl_sdl2.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for svg.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I use windows 10, please help!

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: 3.8.0, just checked few seconds ago!

Comment: Try using 3.7 instead.

Comment: It worked, on 3.7 it installed, but now I have another error. While it's installed its shows me that it doesn't exist. I have this error: 'kivy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Do you know what to do here?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to run `kivy` as a command line command, but that isn't a thing you can do, Kivy is a python module you must import within Python. If that doesn't explain your problem, please give more information about what you're attempting.

Comment: I am trying to import a module kivy but it doesn't show up like tkinter does. What could be the problem?

Comment: `import kivy` isn't expected to make anything "show up". Post an example of some specific code that you believe should do something, but doesn't.

Comment: import kivy('\n')

from kivy.app import App('\n')

cant get further than this because it doesn't recognize the module named kivy.

Comment: Then you don't have Kivy installed in whatever python environment you're running that code from.

Comment: That's the thing, I installed all the lined of code from kivy.org and it shows that its all installed already, but when I try to run a test which is ''python share\kivy-examples\demo\showcase\main.py'' it doesn't recognize. I don't understand how its even possible to be all installed and not recognize at the same time.

Comment: Please post the exact commands you've run to verify that kivy is installed, and the commands you're running to test the example (that don't work).

Comment: 1.python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools, 2.python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew, 3.python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer, 4.python -m pip install kivy.deps.angle, 5.python -m pip install kivy, 6.python -m pip install kivy_examples, and the last one to test if its working is 7.python share\kivy-examples\demo\showcase\main.py.

Comment: What happens if you run `python -m pip install colorama` then `python -c "import colorama"`, assuming you don't have colorama installed already?

Comment: Did that, nothing happened. Do you have any other ideas? And python -c "import colorama" doesn't do anything too, just gives emptiness.

Comment: But if you do `python -c "import kivy"` you get an exception?

Comment: How can I send you a message? Because the error I get is too long for a comment.

Comment: you need to use "python3 -m pip .. " instead of "python -m pip ..."

Comment: I also get this message as of 2020/04/05, maybe kivy doesn't support 3.8 yet? resorted to using python 3.7 as @inclement suggested

Comment: I get the same `ERROR: Dependency` messages with python 3.7.6. Pip continues on from there fine it seems, until `gcc` fails much later with no clear compile error.

Answer (score 25):

This worked for me:

matham commented 15 days ago
We are not likely to release a 1.11.1 version for 3.8 to pypi. However, you can install kivy master using:

```
pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/
```

Comment: This solved my problem in Fedora 27 years later, but I'd love to understand why.  Can someone share some knowledge?

Answer (score 7):

Try using `pip install kivy==2.0.0rc2` or `pip install kivy==2.0.0rc1`

The command: `pip install kivy==2.0.0rc2`

Works with `Windows 10 Pro` and `Python 3.8.3`

And I test it with this code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
 
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text= " Hello Kivy World ")

TestApp().run()
```

Comment: It also works with rc4, arch linux and python 3.8.5

Answer (score 2):

This works in macOS Catalina 10.15.6 with python 3.8.0+

```
pip install kivy==2.0.0rc2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using conda environment:

```
 conda install -c conda-forge kivy
```

works in python 3.8

Answer (score -2):

I am windows 10, with 3.8.2

seems pip install kivy==2.0.0rc2 worked. At least it installed.

time to tell if I can develop with it using 3.8.2