# I tried to install kivy for python 3.8.1 on windows 10 and I have this error

Tags: python, kivy

I tried to install kivy for python 3.8.1 on windows 10 and I have this error.

```
ERROR: Dependency for context.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for compiler.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for context_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for fbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for gl_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for opengl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for opengl_utils.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for shader.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for stencil_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for scissor_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for texture.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for vbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for vertex.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for vertex_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for cgl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for cgl_mock.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for cgl_gl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for cgl_glew.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for cgl_sdl2.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for svg.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Python 3.8 is very new version and some modules may not work with 3.8 - better use Python 3.7

Comment: I had the same issue on Ubuntu using Python 3.8.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try installing it in python 3.7, Kivy may not be updated according to 3.8. Or you can follow this steps that explained in
[How to deal with Kivy installing error in Python 3.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59125232/how-to-deal-with-kivy-installing-error-in-python)

Good luck!

Comment: Thats right, according to the website it is only supported up to Python 3.7. See https://kivy.org/#download

Answer (score 3):

Sorry guys, I passed through these sad moments too, until I ran the following lines.

```
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew --extra-index-url` https://kivy.org/downloads/packages/simple

pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url` https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/
```

Answer (score 2):

This is addressed on the Github issues of the Kivy Project:
https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6563

The Tipp from KiaraKarla:
 *kiarakarla commented on 15 Dec 2019
    We are not likely to release a 1.11.1 version for 3.8 to pypi. However, you can install kivy master using pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/.*

Worked for me to get kivy working with the Sample under Win10 with Python 3.8.2

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps one by one to install the library

For python3.8

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

pip install https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip

pip install kivy.deps.glew

pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2
```

Answer (score 0):

Kivy just released Kivy 2.0. According to it's [release detail](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/releases/tag/2.0.0), Kivy now supports Python 3.6 - 3.9 and no longer supports the Python 2.x version.