# Trying to install Kivy for python but im getting this error

Tags: python, kivy

[image: this is the link to the error image]

I don't understand what is happening. I installed all the dependencies as well but only while installing I'm getting this problem.

I'm new to this coding stuff and wanted to learn kivy.

Comment: Hi, could you tell me what version of python you are running? Kivy is not compatible with python versions 3.8 and up

Comment: I'm running 3.9

Comment: please provide us with full error image so that we can trace out the error.
The image is half cropped or screen shoted

Comment: ok but how do i do that

Comment: its a really big error

Comment: i even downloaded python 3.7.9

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59690863/i-tried-to-install-kivy-for-python-3-8-1-on-windows-10-and-i-have-this-error --- Check this out. Also I am running 3.7.7 if that helps

Answer (score 1):

try typing :

```
python -m pip install kivy==
```

or type this:

```
pip3 install kivy==
```

and hit ENTER than choose from versions the one that can work for you...

work ?

or if you are using py 3.8 try with this :

```
pip3 install --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple kivy[base]
```