# Unable to build wheels for Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to install Kivy but below you can find the error log that I receive when running the installation.

I am new to Python, could someone please advise what I have done wrong?  Had to cut a lot to allow it to post.

```
CMD:(kivy_venv) C:\Users\noodl\PycharmProjects\16Feb>python -m pip install "kivy[base] @ https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip"

Collecting kivy[base]@ https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip
Using cached https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip (24.3 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4
Using cached Kivy_Garden-0.1.5-py3-none-any.whl (4.6 kB)
Collecting docutils
Using cached docutils-0.19-py3-none-any.whl (570 kB)
Collecting pygments
Using cached Pygments-2.14.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting kivy-deps.angle~=0.3.2
Using cached kivy_deps.angle-0.3.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (4.8 MB)
Collecting kivy-deps.sdl2~=0.5.0
Using cached kivy_deps.sdl2-0.5.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (2.6 MB)
Collecting kivy-deps.glew~=0.3.1
Using cached kivy_deps.glew-0.3.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (123 kB)
Collecting pypiwin32
Using cached pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 kB)
Collecting pillow
Using cached Pillow-9.4.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (2.5 MB)
Collecting requests
Using cached requests-2.28.2-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting pywin32>=223
Using cached pywin32-305-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (12.1 MB)
Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2
Using cached charset_normalizer-3.0.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (96 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5Using cached idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
Using cached urllib3-1.26.14-py2.py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
Using cached certifi-2022.12.7-py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: kivy
Building wheel for kivy (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
Building wheel for kivy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
exit code: 1
[884 lines of output]
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\noodl.kivy\logs\kivy_23-02-16_13.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev" 0.3.3
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.3.3
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew_dev" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.5.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2_dev" 0.5.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.2.0.dev0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\noodl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2a8o8ekj\kivy_f60cff3dbd194678b4fad858245dae12\kivy_init_.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.11.2 (tags/v3.11.2:878ead1, Feb  7 2023, 16:38:35) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\noodl\PycharmProjects\16Feb\kivy_venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
<string>:370: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
<string>:373: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
<string>:377: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.

  Current directory is: C:\Users\noodl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2a8o8ekj\kivy_f60cff3dbd194678b4fad858245dae12
  Source and initial build directory is: C:\Users\noodl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2a8o8ekj\kivy_f60cff3dbd194678b4fad858245dae12
  Python path is:
  C:\Users\noodl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2a8o8ekj\kivy_f60cff3dbd194678b4fad858245dae12
  C:\Users\noodl\PycharmProjects\16Feb\kivy_venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process
  C:\Users\noodl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-v6sgt9pe\site
  C:\Program Files\Python311\python311.zip
  C:\Program Files\Python311\DLLs
  C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib
  C:\Program Files\Python311
  C:\Users\noodl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-v6sgt9pe\overlay\Lib\site-packages
  C:\Users\noodl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-v6sgt9pe\normal\Lib\site-packages
  C:\Users\noodl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2a8o8ekj\kivy_f60cff3dbd194678b4fad858245dae12\kivy\modules
  C:\Users\noodl\.kivy\mods
  Found Cython at C:\Users\noodl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-v6sgt9pe\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\__init__.py
  Detected supported Cython version 0.29.32
  User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
  Using this graphics system: OpenGL
  WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

  b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

  GStreamer found via gst.h
  WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)

  b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

  SDL2: found SDL header at C:\Users\noodl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-v6sgt9pe\overlay\Include\SDL2\SDL.h
  SDL2: found SDL_mixer header at C:\Users\noodl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-v6sgt9pe\overlay\Include\SDL2\SDL_mixer.h
  SDL2: found SDL_ttf header at C:\Users\noodl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-v6sgt9pe\overlay\Include\SDL2\SDL_ttf.h
  SDL2: found SDL_image header at C:\Users\noodl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-v6sgt9pe\overlay\Include\SDL2\SDL_image.h
  ERROR: Dependency for context.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for compiler.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for context_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for fbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for gl_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for opengl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for opengl_utils.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for shader.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for stencil_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for scissor_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for texture.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for vbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for vertex.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for vertex_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for cgl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for cgl_mock.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for cgl_gl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for cgl_glew.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for cgl_sdl2.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for svg.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for boxshadow.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  [INFO   ] running bdist_wheel
  [INFO   ] running build
  [INFO   ] running build_py

311\kivy\core\video[INFO   ] copying kivy\core\video\video_gstplayer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\kivy\core\video[INFO   ] copying kivy\core\video\video_null.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\kivy\core\video

IC:\Program Files\Python311\Include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" /TcC:\Users\noodl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2a8o8ekj\kivy_f60cff3dbd194678b4fad858245dae12\kivy\weakproxy.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\Users\noodl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2a8o8ekj\kivy_f60cff3dbd194678b4fad858245dae12\kivy\weakproxy.obj
_event.c
properties.c
weakproxy.c
C:\Program Files\Python311\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
C:\Program Files\Python311\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directoryC:\Program Files\Python311\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
311\Release\Users\noodl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2a8o8ekj\kivy_f60cff3dbd194678b4fad858245dae12\kivy\graphics\fbo.obj
compiler.c
context_instructions.c
C:\Program Files\Python311\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
fbo.c
C:\Program Files\Python311\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
C:\Program Files\Python311\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
  [INFO   ] building 'kivy.graphics.gl_instructions' extension
  [INFO   ] ["C          ]\Program Files\Microsoft Visual 
  _clock.c
  cgl_debug.c
  C:\Program Files\Python311\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
  C:\Program Files\Python311\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
  C:\Program Files\Python311\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
  [INFO   ] building 'kivy.core.window.window_info' extension
  [INFO   ] building 'kivy.graphics.tesselator' extension
  [INFO   ] building 'kivy.graphics.svg' extension
  [INFO   ] creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\Users\noodl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2a8o8ekj\kivy_f60cff3dbd194678b4fad858245dae12\kivy\core\window
d64-cpython-311\Release\Users\noodl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2a8o8ekj\kivy_f60cff3dbd194678b4fad858245dae12\kivy\lib/gstplayer_gstplayer.objaudio_sdl2.cC:\Program Files\Python311\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directoryC:\Program Files\Python311\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory_clipboard_sdl2.c
_gstplayer.c
C:\Program Files\Python311\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
C:\Program Files\Python311\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
  Building extensions in parallel using 4 cores
  Updated build directory to: build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
  Build configuration is:
   * use_rpi = 0
   * use_egl = 0
   * use_opengl_es2 = 0
   * use_opengl_mock = 0
   * use_sdl2 = 1
   * use_pangoft2 = 0
   * use_ios = 0
   * use_android = 0
   * use_mesagl = 0
   * use_x11 = 0
   * use_wayland = 0
   * use_gstreamer = 1
   * use_avfoundation = 0
   * use_osx_frameworks = 0
   * debug_gl = 0
   * kivy_sdl_gl_alpha_size = 8
   * debug = False
  Updated build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\kivy\include\config.h
  Updated C:\Users\noodl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2a8o8ekj\kivy_f60cff3dbd194678b4fad858245dae12\kivy\include\config.h
  Updated build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\kivy\include\config.pxi
  Updated C:\Users\noodl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2a8o8ekj\kivy_f60cff3dbd194678b4fad858245dae12\kivy\include\config.pxi
  Updated build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\kivy\setupconfig.py
  Updated C:\Users\noodl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2a8o8ekj\kivy_f60cff3dbd194678b4fad858245dae12\kivy\setupconfig.py
  Detected compiler is msvc
   error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for kivy
Failed to build kivy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for kivy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have reinstalled software multiple times, and made sure I followed [the installation guide](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html#kivy-source-install) but no luck yet.

Comment: Do you absolutely need Python 3.11 and the cutting edge version of Kivy?  Have you tried with Python 3.10 and the base install for 3.10 (seeing as that's the latest officially supported. version)?

Comment: i have tried 3.8/ 3.9 and 3.10 as well as when those versions were available I tested Kivy and it still wont work

Comment: Looks like this is a recurring problem, mostly due to missing dependencies or trying to install on a version of Python that Kivy doesn't yet officially support.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59125232/how-to-deal-with-kivy-installing-error-in-python-3-8

Comment: You could try the pre-compiled wheels option on the installation instructions page.  I would recommend starting with a fresh venv.