# Kivy [Window] Unable to find any valuable Window provider

Tags: python, kivy

I have a problem when trying to run a simple code in VS Code for an app using Kivy Lib.

I already installed all the components to run kivy.

The code I use:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.1') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

The problem I have is this (in the log)
... things working and ...

> [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
> [CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
> Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command
> line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to
> identify potential causes sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: Le
> module spécifié est introuvable.   File
> "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\kivy\core_*init*_.py",
> line 63, in core_select_lib
> fromlist=[modulename], level=0)   File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py",
> line 27, in 
> from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage
>
> [CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.

[image]

Comment: Why are you using square brackets in the last if statement? There's no need to.

Comment: plenty to read here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697876/unable-to-get-a-window-abort

Comment: It didn't change anything daniel : / , abrar I read it al land tried it all for the past 7 hours :( the problem is in the sdl2 I think  but the file is normal I checked , everything is installed correctly : (